# UIslider with custom background images

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

My code so far in getting slider to work with custom background image

```
 self.slider.setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "thumb"), for: .normal)
 self.slider.setMinimumTrackImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "slider"), for: .normal)
 self.slider.setMaximumTrackImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "slider2"), for: .normal)
 self.slider.setValue(0.5, animated: true)
```

[image]

I want a slider like temperature where user scroll and it fill with color. But unable to do so. Please help

This one is not working anymore
[Dashed slider](https://github.com/ahmetws/DashedSlider)

Comment: You are setting the ***same image*** for both Minimum and Maximum Track Image? That will make the "slider bar" constant. Try using different images... Having the slider "fill with color" is pretty much the default.

Comment: Sorry, I am using different Image. Still same issue

Comment: Show a screen-capture of your result.

Comment: please check the image

Comment: OK - you want your "tick-mark" image to be the Max Track image, and your "fill-color" image to be the Min Track image. Swap them, and see how it looks.

Comment: Sorry I am not 100% sure when you say swap. I simply tried what you said, but in both cases. the track moves in the edge. Not fully from min to max. I would say its a progress

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on how to create and set up your images for a custom UISlider - I think it can give you what you are trying to do: https://www.raywenderlich.com/32167/photoshop-tutorial-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uislider

Comment: Thanks DonMag for your help. Your link is good 
But best way to fully customize is to use uiview for that.

Comment: Well, sure... depending on what exactly one wants to do. If your goal was to match that "Dashed Slider" you linked to, I took a look at it -- it was a simple process to update to Swift 3...